# Proper explanation of the hydraulic lift

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lift

How is hydraulic lift useful? According to energy conservation it is not possible. Can somebody please explain how a hydraulic lift works?

Answer (score 2):

An important Application for Pascal law is Hydraulic lift used to lift heavier object,
It consist of a liquid container which has pistons fitted into small and large opening cylinders. IF $a_1 \space a_2$ are areas of Pistons A and B. F is Force applied on A and W is the load on B then,

$\text{From Pascal law,}$
$$ \frac{F}{a_1}=\frac{W}{a_2}$$

$$W=F\frac{a_2}{a_1}$$
This is the load that can be lifted by applying force F on A. $\frac{a1/a2 is called as Mechanical Advantage. [image]